# Can ubuntu replace Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, wine

So I love Ubuntu as it is faster, and looks better and is more user friendly. In comparison, Windows just looks shady. But the problem is all sorts of applications I need are readily available for Windows (Emulators, power point, excel, word, illustrator etc.). I tried wine to install all my windows apps into Ubuntu but there's always some sort of bug or error which are unfixable. I understand, they're based on different kernels. You could tell me to use virtual box bu then I'd rather just use the Windows partition on my PC.
Bottom line is, is there any way I can still use the applications I used on windows but on Ubuntu?

Comment: I will add this as a comment, rather than an answer, since you are looking to use the very same applications that you use in windows. There are excellent alternatives to what you list, such as libre office, that work beautifully in Ubuntu. In my opinion, Ubuntu can absolutely replace Windows, provided your work doesn't absolutely require you to use Windows for whatever reason.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Personally I use Ubuntu for virtually everything. I do have one legacy app that only runs under Windows and I use a VM for that. Bottom line, no but there are excellent alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I still have the disks for applications like Microsoft Office and Photoshop that I used to use on Windows, but I don't even bother to install them in Ubuntu with Wine anymore. Why? Replacements for Windows software in Ubuntu are better because they are up-to-date. Especially since Ubuntu introduced snap packages and the Snap Store, replacements for Windows software in Ubuntu are up-to-date to the latest version. This makes a big difference, so I have replaced Windows with Ubuntu.

You're still going to need to keep Windows installed if you like to play the latest popular video games.

Answer (score 1):

**Can ubuntu replace Windows?**

YES! Ubuntu CAN replace windows. It's very good operating system that supports pretty much all hardware Windows OS does (unless the device is very specific and drivers were only ever made for Windows, see below).

**Can I do everything I currently do daily on Windows, but on Ubuntu?**

What Ubuntu cannot do is tell the application or game maker to make it work on Ubuntu.
If your daily work depends on applications that were only written to work on Windows, you have to look for replacements and adjust your work habits.

i.e replacement for Office is LibreOffice or you can switch to Google Docs, I didn't really find ANYTHING that the office alternative cannot do, yet. There are ton of replacements. It's just how much you're ready to go out of your comfort zone and learn new things ;) That pretty much applies to everything you use daily.

says me, long time Windows user long ago, who only comes back to Windows for games that never got their linux release and didn't get to wine SteamOS program.
For everything other: I don't miss Windows, found very good replacements for everything I use at work.